# DropDownList in Footer Template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need added to the beginning of the **DropDownList DDL** one row empty:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
```

I've tried using these two different solutions without success.

Here is my code.

**Solution #1**

```
<FooterTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Small">
    <asp:ListItem Text="------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
</FooterTemplate>
```

**Solution #2**

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
    DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL");

    sql = " SELECT DISTINCT FROM .....; ";

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);
    DDL.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    DDL.DataTextField = "combo";
    DDL.DataValueField = "combo";
    DDL.DataBind();
    DDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("------", ""));
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`AppendDataBoundItems`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx) to true:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Small">
   <asp:ListItem Text="------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This works declaratively (as above) or programmatically:

```
DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL");
DDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("------", ""));

sql = " SELECT DISTINCT FROM .....; ";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);
DDL.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
DDL.DataTextField = "combo";
DDL.DataValueField = "combo";
DDL.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you try to make a datasource to dropbox so its prevent any add because in the default the add is disable .... simply and this tag to your dropdown element :

```
<asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" .... >
```

thats mean the dropdown  will add the element u add in static to the datasource u have

so now i guess the two solution u mention will work

but if u want to write it in the behind code remember to do :

```
dropdown.DataBind();
```

to refresh the dropdown element .

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other answers provided here is along the same route of your second attempt. Instead of the `Add()` method, use the `Insert()` method. Just insert another item into the list *after* you bind it, giving it a specific index. In your case, 0.

```
DDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("------"));
```